# How to list specific dated folders in a root folder to use with wzzip (winzip) command line in my batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, winzip

What I am looking to do is, using winzip command line (wzzip) inside my batch script, and zip any folders that have 201409 (That is Sept 2014)(for example) in the folder name into one zip file.
There are folders (which contain many files each) for mulitple months but I need to keep them grouped by month.

I currently run DIR and output a list of filenames based on a filter I place such as 201409. It grabs all filenames from the current folder that contain that 201409. I then call wzzip to go through the list of filenames that I made and zip them all into one zip file with a name that I gave it.

I've tried every combination of switches for the DIR command that I can find. It works great when populating a text file of filenames that fit a specific filter. I just can't figure out how to do it for folders like in this example.

I have to keep this using winzip so please do not offer ideas using other applications, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DIR /ad`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx) to filter directory listings to contain only directories entries.